# Svelte creates anomalous dictionary item

Tags: svelte

I have a function which creates a dict in Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b579531c2ed4cc89a82655c76400235?version=3.52.0)

```
function createUser() {
    var user_record = {
        display_hand_type:  {
            'solo': false,
            'duo': false,
        },

        set_hands:  {
            'solo': [],
            'duo': [],
        },

        use_set_hands: {
            'solo': false,
            'duo': false,
        },
    }
    console.log(user_record.set_hands);
    return user_record;
}
```

It works perfectly in the REPL, but on my development environment the console shows

```
{solo: Array(0), duo: Array(0)}
duo: []
solo: []
undefined: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

The extra *undefined* element disappears if I comment out the *use_set_hands* element

I can only assume that something is going on in the Svlete compiler. Is there any way I can check this?

Comment: There is only one log statement in the REPL. Please include all the code that causes the issue *in the question*; presumably there are more log statements.

Comment: No - The REPL is identical to my function in development

Comment: I have expanded the console output

Comment: Well, that doesn't make any sense. Have you checked the compiled output?

Comment: bundle.js is the same as source

Comment: What's your bundler, are your on svelte-kit, what's your node version?

Comment: rollup, not using svelte-kit, node 16.16 (because certain Netlify functions do not work on later)